# Mark as persistent an ActiveRecord item recovered from serialisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where a set of items, known to be in the database, is recovered from a serialised json array, *including their **id**s*, so they can be reshaped to ActiveRecord model instances just calling new, without access to the database:

```
for itm in a do
   item = Item.new(itm)
   itmlist << item
emd
```

Now, the problem is, how to tell ActiveRecord that these elements are already persisted and not new? If `item.new_record?` is true, a `item.save` will fail because Rails will insert instead of update.

The goal is to make sure that Rails does update, without any extra queries to the database. The closest thing I have got is

```
item = Item.new(itm)
item.instance_variable_set(:@new_record, false)
```

with plays with ActiveRecord Internals

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand the question but if you just want to update all the items the following will work

```
a.each do |item_hash| 
  Item.find(item_hash["id"]).update(item_hash.except("id"))
end
```

If the `Item` may or may not exist then

```
a.each do |item| 
  item = Item.find(item_hash["id"]) || Item.new 
  item.update(item_hash.except("id"))
end
```

Neither one of these options will handle validation failures. Depending on your usage the following could be useful

```
all_items = a.map do |item_hash| 
 item = Item.find(item_hash["id"]) || Item.new
 item.assign_attributes(item_hash.except("id"))
end
pass,fail = all_items.partition(&:save)
```

If you only care about the failures you can change this to: `fail = all_items.reject(&:save)`

If there are a substantial number of items there are more performant alternatives as well that avoid so many queries. e.g. `Item.where(id: a.map {|i| i["id"]})`

Comment: Yep, my problem with the pattern find + update is that it reads the database in cases where there is not need, if we know for sure that the item exists. I have already got the items from the serialized data, so I do not need to read them again.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `reload`-ing works:

```rb
thing = Thing.last
thing_attributes = thing.attributes

same_thing = Thing.new(thing_attributes)
same_thing.new_record? # => true

same_thing.reload
same_thing.new_record? # => false
```

From the question, I see that your concern is only about ActiveRecord performing an `INSERT` query instead of the intended `UPDATE`, so reloading shouldn't be a problem. But, if my guess is wrong and you don't even want to reload, then it might be difficult without fiddling with the internals of ActiveRecord since it doesn't provide any way to instantiate already persisted records.

---

#### Possible alternate solution

Pardon me if the solution won't work in your case, but instead of serialising the entire objects, just serialise an array of IDs. So that you can re-fetch them in one go:

```rb
Thing.where(id: the_array_of_ids)
```

Comment: Yep, that is the traditional solution, recover from where. It is a pity because if one has already the record, e.g. because it has been processed with javascript and returned back to the server, one should not need such reloading.